# error when 2 nodes collide

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skphysicsbody

I keep getting an error when 2 nodes collide, this is the code I am using for collision detection:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!) {

    var firstBody:SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody:SKPhysicsBody

    if(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask){
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    }else{
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }


        if((firstBody.categoryBitMask & coin2Category) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & playerCategory) != 0){
            var bodyAAC = contact.bodyA.node as SKSpriteNode //error pointing at this line: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value
            if CGRectIntersectsRect(kikker.frame, bodyAAC.frame) {
                coinslos = coinslos + 10
                coinlabel.text = "\(coinslos)"
                bodyAAC.removeFromParent()
                coinSound()
            }
        }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: its possible that contact.bodyA.node is not an `SKSpriteNode`. what are the types of bodies you are checking for collision?

Answer (score 0):

First to avoid the crash

This:

```
        var bodyAAC = contact.bodyA.node as SKSpriteNode
        if CGRectIntersectsRect(kikker.frame, bodyAAC.frame) {
            coinslos = coinslos + 10
            coinlabel.text = "\(coinslos)"
            bodyAAC.removeFromParent()
            coinSound()
        }
```

Should be changed to this:

```
        if let bodyAAC = contact.bodyA.node as? SKSpriteNode {
            if CGRectIntersectsRect(kikker.frame, bodyAAC.frame) {
                 coinslos = coinslos + 10
                 coinlabel.text = "\(coinslos)"
                 bodyAAC.removeFromParent()
                 coinSound()
            }
        }
```

You need to check optionals before trying to use them.

However rakeshbs is correct. In whichever collision this is catching, bodyA.node isn't an SKSpriteNode. I don't know the specifics of your code but you're not using or accessing any SKSpriteNode specific properties/methods.

You might try changing:

```
            if let bodyAAC = contact.bodyA.node as? SKSpriteNode {
```

To:

```
            if let bodyAAC = contact.bodyA.node {
```

If that still doesn't work then it doesn't look like bodyA is attached to any node at all.